# Singular value decomposition

Tags: missing-data, nonlinear, svd

Can singular value decomposition used to impute missing values in highly nonlinear process under multiple input and multiple output behavior?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you believe the SVD could be applied?  It doesn't work with missing values, so how would it impute them?

Comment: Yes provided the complete case analysis to generate an imputation model is adequately powered. But it could only do a form of mean imputation which is inefficient.